# Why is the full eigenfunction a product of eigenfunctions and not a sum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

For example suppose there is a two electron system. Why is the full eigenfunction a product of the spatial eigenfunction and spin-wave-function for the two electron system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a product of functions, it's a tensor product.

In a sense, you have two systems: The spatial system and the spin system. The combined system is thus the tensor product of the two spaces by the fundamental postulates and an eigenfunction is a (tensor!) product of eigenfunctions.

Not that an addition of two wave functions wouldn't make sense: They are functions of completely different spaces (spatial space, spin), so how do you define addition? The meaningful addition is between functions from the same function space (as is the meaningful multiplication). The tensor product, however, is a product between spaces, hence its elements are combinations between different parts of a system.